# Bootstrap modal with delay and show only once with cookie

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cookies, modal-dialog, delay

I have a code that allows the modal to delay. And, if the user click on either  YES (which has an id="closemodal"), or NO (which has data-dismiss="modal") link, the modal will not show up again until the user leaves the **page** and then comes back to the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
        setTimeout(function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }, 10000);
        $('#closemodal').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide') });
});
</script>
```

But, what I want is that the modal doesn't show back up at all after being shown once already to the user. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026153/how-can-i-show-the-modal-in-the-twitter-bootstrap-just-once). I have combined it with my code as shown below.

But, I can't seem to get this to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if($.cookie('msg') != null && $.cookie('msg') != "")
    {
        $("div#myModal.modal, .modal-backdrop").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }, 10000);
        $.cookie('msg', 1 ); //moved this up and changed 'str' to 1
        $('#closemodal').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide'); });
    }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED:** Just in case this helps anyone. This is what I ended up with with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189428/display-a-popup-only-once-per-user).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($.cookie('prepare') != 'seen'){
    $.cookie('prepare', 'seen', { expires: 365, path: '/' }); // Set it to last a year, for example.
    setTimeout(function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }, 1000);
    $('#closemodal').click(function() // You are clicking the close button
    {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide'); // Now the pop up is hiden.
    });
    $('#myModal').click(function(e) 
        {
        $('#myModal').fadeOut(); 
    });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use at [Duct Tape DANYOL](https://ducttapedanyol.com)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("shown=true")<0) {
        var show = function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
        };

        $(window).load(function(){
            var timer = window.setTimeout(show,5000);
        });
    }
    document.cookie = "shown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just dumping the code? That way others can understand and learn from it.

Comment: You can just copy and paste it and play around with it if you want. That's how I learn :D Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, this is not how stackoverflow works. This is not a site for code dumps, but for explanations. As you can tell by the votes you received.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Hahaha ^. Got'eeem.